# Date validation in angularJS MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: angularjs, validation, date

> I Need a custom directive/other way, which validate the date format (MM/DD/YYYY). Please help.

```
    <body ng-app="dateInputExample">
    <script>
       angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
         .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

         }]);
    </script>
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
       <label for="exampleInput">Enter Date:</label>
       <input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" required />
       <div role="alert">
         <!-- for error display -->
         <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
             Required!</span>
         <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.date">
             Not a valid date!</span>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
```

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pi466O9rDxSjrfup0GMl?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

It is neither possible nor wise to enforce the format in which the date value is displayed. The date format is set due to the users locale setting, so that the user always sees the date in a format that he/she is used to.

Therefore you should not try to override it with your own preferred format.